# Is this series convergent or not???

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } 3^{\pi^{2}n}\left[\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right]^{n^{3}}$

What test do I use to find out if the series is convergent or divergent? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you mean a lower case pi?

Comment: Divergence test might work.

Comment: you sum does not converge

Comment: @Tucker Yes, of course

Comment: People, let's pay attention to the edits we approve and let's please stop approving edits that introduce bad grammar.

Comment: Perhaps a good idea to try to show that $$3^{\pi^{2}n}\left(\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right)^{n^{3}}$$ doesn't go to $0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the root test, you only have to calculate
$$
\limsup 3^{\pi^2}{\left[\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n} \right)\right]}^{n^2}.
$$